# Get element from a type ocaml

Tags: ocaml

New to Ocaml so asking a very basic question.

If I have a type say `type foobar = foo * bar` and a variable `a` of type foobar. Is it possible to get just the value of foo from a with a method? Is there any other way than pattern matching? Also, in this case how would you apply pattern matching? Since the type declared is not declared as `type foobar = | Foobar of foo * bar`?

Answer (score 3):

You can match against a pair like this:

```
# type intfloat = int * float;;
type intfloat = int * float
# let x : intfloat = (3, 5.5);;
val x : intfloat = (3, 5.5)
# let (int_part, _) = x in int_part;;
- : int = 3
# let (_, float_part) = x in float_part;;
- : float = 5.5
```

There is a function (not a method) `fst` that returns the first element of a pair.

```
# fst x;;
- : int = 3
```

However, the definition of `fst` necessarily uses pattern matching:

```
let fst (a, b) = a
```

In this definition, the construct `(a, b)` is a pattern that matches a pair.

Pattern matching is an essential part of OCaml, not just a fancy optional feature.